# Group by place names in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to group by a list of lists I have. The list is given below:

```
[[[-50,98],1,2,'San Antonio,TX'],[[-52,99],3,4,'San Antonio,TX']]
```

The output I am expecting is given below:

```
{'San Antonio,TX': [[-50,98],2, 3]}
```

More precisely the first element of the inner list in the output need to be either of the 2 first elements. Second element of inner list in the output is average of the second elements in the inner lists of the input. Third element of inner list in the output is average of the third elements in the inner lists of the input.

This is actually a small version of the problem. The initial list of lists I have will be having 1000 or more lists.

Thanks

Comment: Are the averages truncated to int, or floats?

Comment: The averages truncated to floats..I put int here for easy understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contents of test.py

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


def aggregate(data):
    result = []
    data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(3))
    for k, g in groupby(data, itemgetter(3)):
        g = list(g)
        n = len(g)  # Cast to float if you want average to be float in python 2
        x1 = g[0][0]
        x2 = sum(x[1] for x in g)
        x3 = sum(x[2] for x in g)
        d = {k: [x1, x2/n, x3/n]}  # This is what you want for each group
        result.append(d)

    return result


def main():
    data = [[[-50,98], 1, 2, 'San Antonio,TX'],
            [[-52,99], 3, 4, 'San Antonio,TX']]
    result = aggregate(data)
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
In [12]: run test.py
[{'San Antonio,TX': [[-50, 98], 2, 3]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Appreciate your help

Comment: @YEDURAGBABU If this answer is correct, consider marking it as the answer by clicking on the "tick" below the number on the left margin, or even upvoting it.